# How to use Calendar icon with input Field in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using bsDatepicker in Angular for DateField. I want to add calendar icon to the Date input Field.

Here's my code:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="lable label-default">Entry Start Date<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" bsDatepicker name='EntryStartDate' 
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.EntryStartDate" autocomplete='off' [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }"
                        [outsideClick]="true" [maxDate]='tourDetails.EntryEndDate' dateFormat="dd-MMM-yyyy" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="lable label-default">Entry End Date<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" bsDatepicker name='EntryEndDate' 
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.EntryEndDate" autocomplete='off' [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }"
                        [outsideClick]="true" [minDate]='tourDetails.EntryStartDate' required>
                    </div>
```

I need calendar icon to the input field at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/) for using icons in your page. Just use the css file of font-awesome. Or you can even use it with a referral link.

checkout the varieties of [calendar icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=calender&m=free) they provide.

just go through their introduction/getting started menu, and find out how to use it.
Its quite simple and reliable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
<div class="m-5">
  <div [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group ">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Datepicker"
          bsDatepicker
          value="{{ myDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }}"
          [(ngModel)]="myDate"
          formControlName="date"
          [isOpen]="isOpen"
        />

      </div>

      <!--          calendar icon      -->
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-4 col-md-4 form-group">           
        <span  (click)="isOpen = !isOpen"
         class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```